# How can I bypass WIndows 7 boot loader when dual booting Linux Mint 14

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, linux-mint, grub2

As of this morning my dual-boot attempt went south. This as far as I can see is  mainly due to the windows boot loader and grub 2 and I'm really not sure how to fix the issue other than deleting Mint 14 and retrying.  I used e boot easybsd in windows to set up the boot menu and it worked last night then reacted bad this morning, this issue is as follows:

When I first boot up the laptop i come to the Linux boot loader and I scroll all the way down to the bottom and select Win 7 then it immediately throws my into the windows boot loader where it gives me the choice for Win 7 or Mint 14. If I choose Mint 14 from it growls at with a message that scrolls across top of screen quickly and tosses me back to grub 2 and starts the process  again. So it seems to me that everyone wants to start from their own respective boot loaders.
The error message that displays is

> Try (hd0,0) : NTFS5 : no ang0 Try (hd0,1) NTFS5 : Initialize variable
>   space... Starting cmain()... (hd0,3) [multiboot- kledge , loadaddr =
>   0x100000 , text - and - data = 0x6739 , bss = 0x0 , entry = 0x100968]

Comment: Have you tried pressing the PAUSE/PrintScr key as the error appears? For text-based error messages (i.e. not in some fancy graphics mode) the PAUSE key typically does just that. Unpause with ENTER.  Please update your question with the error when you capture it!

Comment: @RobM - Hey here is the error message that its spitting out at me:

Comment: @RobM - Hey here is the error message that its spitting out at me:     **Try (hd0,0) : NTFS5 : no ang0  Try (hd0,1) NTFS5 :  Initialize variable space... Starting cmain()... (hd0,3) [multiboot- kledge , loadaddr = 0x100000 , text - and - data = 0x6739 , bss = 0x0 , entry = 0x100968]**

Answer (score 0):

Grub seems to be corrupted. You can try to `repair grub` using Linux Mint `Live-CD`. Follow the steps outlined in this [article](http://www.ohbuntu.blogspot.in/2009/11/repair-grub2-after-install-windows-7.html). It explains with an old ubuntu release but the steps are same for all. After the repair, reboot and remove the live-cd. It should hopefully give you the grub menu back.

Comment: in the output from the grub repair  look for  windows 7 loader  in the "found ...... on /dev/sdXY  readout